# Система централизованной конфигурации серверов?

Tags: администрирование, configuration

А какие самые простые для использования системы управления конфигурациями? Желательно с web gui.

Есть локальные сервера, нужно подключать их к единой сети и настроить определенным образом. По сути установить там некоторые библиотеки и пакеты. 
А так же изменить конфигурацию на всех серверах, например обновить какой то пакет.
Посмотрел на chef, ansimble и другие, но кажется они слишком навороченные.

То есть сейчас задача такая чтобы подключить сервер по сети, установить туда ОС ubuntu, дальше например запустить там `sh`-файл, который установит несколько пакетов через `apt-get install`. И всё. А потом возможно на каждом из них что то доустановить или обновить в дальнейшем (желательно через web gui).
Ищу простой способ сделать это, кроме ручного.

Comment: Если нужно ненавороченную — `cat вашскрипт.sh | ssh хост "bash -s --"` в цикле. А «web gui» по-моему автоматически означает навороченную :)

Comment: Ну я несколько лет присматривался к синтаксису и руководствам по разным системам и остановился на `ansible`. Советую к нему присмотреться внимательнее.